# How set child router in react-router4?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have app used `withRouter`, and component with routers

```
class Routes extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
                <Route exact path="/tv/:id" component={TV} />
            </Switch>
        )
    }
}
```

in component `TV` i want to use child router, but it does not work.

And that's why I'm using in `TV` component. Path in TV component dynamic

```
<Link to={`${this.props.location.pathname}/season-${el.season_number}`}>
 <Route path={`/tv/${this.props.match.path}/season-:season_number`} component={TVSeason}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `this.props.match.url` to handle links and routes dynamically:

```
<Link to={`${this.props.match.url}/season-${el.season_number}`}>
<Route path={`${this.props.match.url}/season-:season_number`} component={TVSeason}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Router will look for switch to to see the Match and load then the component, otherwise should a default component.

you can use:

```
class Routes extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
            <Route exact path="/tv/:id" component={TV} />
            <Route path="/tv/:id/:id" component={TVSeason}/>
        </Switch>
    )
}
```

}

and at `TV` Component can use only `Link` like: `<Link to={`${this.props.location.pathname}/season-${el.season_number}`}>`

Comment: you can use route outside of switch if it's dynamic

Comment: But me need render TVSeason in TV component, so then i need add router TV outside Switch?

Comment: Well you can another method, while you can add the just remove `<Route path={`/tv/${this.props.match.path}/season-:season_number`} component={TVSeason}/>` from `TV` component to be `<Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/season-:season_number`} component={TVSeason}/>` and Should work.